# facing an error with registration btn

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I fill the registration form and click on the button to move to user panel it does not move to the user panel, it freezes on the registration. In the user panel code behind it shows this message:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string sqlstatment = "INSERT INTO UserInfo (UID, FN, LN, Password, RePass, Email,Country, State,City, Post, Img, Logo,RegDate) VALUES (@UID,@FN,@LN,@Password,@RePass,@Email,@Country,@State,@City,@Post,@Img,@Logo,@RegDate)";

        cmd.Connection = cn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;

        //Insert the parameters first
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", UsrNme.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", fnbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", lnamebox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", passtxtbx1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RePass", passtxtbx2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", countrdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", statedrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citiesdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", postbox.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img", persimgFileUpload1.FileName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Logo", logoFileUpload.FileName);

        //Get the Current Date Time here
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegDate", DateTime.Now);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UsrNme.Text))
        {
            Lblcheckusername.Text = "User Name Already Exist";
            Lblcheckusername.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            Lblcheckusername.Text = "User Name Available";
            Lblcheckusername.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }

        if (persimgFileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            persimgFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/users/" + persimgFileUpload1.FileName));
        }

        if (logoFileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            logoFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/Logos/" + logoFileUpload.FileName));
        }

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
        ad.Fill(ds);
        Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");
    }
```

Here is the user panel codebehind where the error appears on the first code line:

```
USRNMElbl.Text = Session["UsrNme"].ToString();
if (Session["UsrNme"] != null)
{
}

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable countrycascd = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("select [countryID],[country] FROM [countr]", con);
        adaptar.Fill(countrycascd);
        countrdrdolst.DataSource = countrycascd;
        countrdrdolst.DataTextField = "country";
        countrdrdolst.DataValueField = "countryID";
        countrdrdolst.DataBind();
    }
    countrdrdolst.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Välj land", "0"));
}

if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    DataTable Sectiondt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BeravaConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adaptar = new SqlDataAdapter("select [CateID],[Category] FROM [Section]", con);
        adaptar.Fill(Sectiondt);
        Catedrdoads.DataSource = Sectiondt;
        Catedrdoads.DataTextField = "Category";
        Catedrdoads.DataValueField = "CateID";
        Catedrdoads.DataBind();
    }
    Catedrdoads.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select Section", "0"));
}
}

protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
}
protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
}
protected void LinkButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
}
protected void LinkButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 3;
}
protected void addadsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Guid newGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sc);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string sqlstatment = "INSERT INTO [ads] ([Section], [Category], [UID], [AdsTit], [AdsDesc], [Country], [State], [City], [AdsPrice], [Img1], [img2], [img3], [img4], [img5], [Wtags]) VALUES (@Section, @Category, @UID, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State, @City, @AdsPrice, @Img1, @img2, @img3, @img4, @img5, @Wtags)";

    cmd.Connection = cn;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = sqlstatment;

    //Insert the parameters first
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Catedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", SubCatedrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", USRNMElbl.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsTit", addadstittxtbx.Text);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsDesc", Editor1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", countrdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", statedrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", citiesdrdolst.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AdsPrice", adsaddpristxtbx.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", FileUpload1.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img2", FileUploadImg2.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img3", FileUploadImg3.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img4", FileUploadImg4.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img5", FileUploadImg5.FileName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wtags", addadswtagtxtbtn.Text);

    SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
    ad.Fill(ds);

    Response.Redirect("User panel.aspx");
}
```

Comment: In which line are you getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be your Session["UsrNme"] is null

```
if (Session["UsrNme"] != null)
{
      USRNMElbl.Text = Session["UsrNme"].ToString();
}
else
{
     return;
}
```

You could also read http://www.codingdefined.com/2014/06/object-reference-not-set.html